# What do you call a unit of beer within a pack?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

This is for academic writing purposes.

I am trying to come up with a word that could indistinguishably describe a bottle or a can within a pack of beer. I cannot say "a unit" because "a unit" in my field means a pack (of beer). For example, when we say, price per unit of beer, it means, price per 1 pack of beer. I, on the other hand, seek to say "price per bottle/can" within such unit. Is there a word that is equally suitable to describe either a bottle or a can?

Comment: Have you considered that the word *unit* might be misapplied here? Are you using the words *outer* and *inner* anywhere? One solution is 24 *units* in an *inner* (the box of 24 tins which is taken through the checkout), and those retail boxes are supplied in an *outer*. If the retail boxes are simply supplied on a pallet, then they become the outer.

Comment: Bear in mind that when talking about alcoholic drinks, [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_alcohol) has another meaning as well.  The phrase "Price Per Unit" is used in [legislation in Scotland](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/asp/2012/4/pdfs/asp_20120004_en.pdf), referring to units of Alcohol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**container** as in [open container laws](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_open_container_laws)

Comment: Easily misunderstood in the world of distribution. You could ask someone to get you one container and end up with a giant steel box.

Comment: @Caleb And then it could be 20', 40', or 53', either standard or high-cube... The permutations are many.

Answer (score 57):

What's wrong with *beer*?

> There are 12 beers in a 12-pack. The price is 70¢ a beer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53048/discussion-on-answer-by-fuhrmanator-what-do-you-call-a-unit-of-beer-within-a-pac).

Comment: Incidentally, a friend of mine from Sudbury, Ontario says *beer* at this juncture. That is, the plural is as invisible as it is in *deer*. "We had about six beer." Very strange to my ears...

Answer (score 39):

In the UK trade this is sometimes referred to as a **"single"**. Usually meaning one bottle from a case of 6, 12 etc, where the case is the main stock keeping unit (SKU) for distribution. It could also apply to cans.

E.g. "Quantity: 3 cases, 1 single." or "Quantity: 1 cases, 3 singles."

You'll see this reported on customs and excise forms along with liquid volume and alcohol volume and other tax related measures of quantity.

Comment: In the USA, this is also what I've commonly heard one called.

Comment: I'm in the Midwest USA.  I have _never_ heard this term.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Nonsense... you heard it fifteen minutes ago! :D

Comment: I've heard it in a singles bar.

Comment: A single would be the best word to use in this case.

Answer (score 20):

[*Serving*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/serving) makes sense:

> a single portion of food or drink; helping

Comment: +1 Unless, of course, they are promoting the low calories, in which case they will suggest there are 12 servings per pack.

Comment: 'Serving' is inappropriate. Nobody would call a single can or bottle of beer (whether in/from a multipack or not) a 'serving' or 'helping'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you suggesting a serving of beer is more or less than 12 oz?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth nobody? I think in the context it conveys the idea while being unlikely to infringe on other terminology.

Comment: Hey @jimm101, good thinking! I've generally thought of 'serving' as referring to a portion of food/drink for consumption, as opposed to shipment, sale, or storage. Sometimes, cans of food or drink indicate that they contain more than one serving, no? Just a thought :)

Comment: @Yasha There is no recommend serving size from the US nutrition guidelines, but a "standard" drink is a 12 oz beer, which is the closest we have. Again, In this context it's unambiguous.

Comment: @jimm101 what if it's a pack of 16-oz cans?

Comment: @phoog Then it's a 16oz serving. :-) I think the general point here is that "serving" is interpretable from the context, does not overlap with any other word in use, and is defined for the purposes of a technical document as having a meaning (i.e. is jargon). Other popular answers don't meet those criteria.

Comment: I think you might have to use this as a noun defined in the paper.  Define "serving" to mean "one container (can, bottle or otherwise) within a packaged unit."  That way the issues with any other meaning of "serving" in the beer industry is taken care of.

Comment: The question is 'What do you call a unit of beer within a pack?' not 'Can you find a way to get round the problem we have with our non-standard terminology?' (which I'm pretty sure would rapidly become off-topic). 'Serving' is not standard English for a can/bottle. And @bib: Are you suggesting that 12 oz cans are the only ones beer is supplied in?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've understood every argument made until this one. Defining a term within the context of a technical paper when one is not readily available is *exactly* what is called for. The only question is which term would do the most work for the reader, borrowing from existing vocabulary. The spread of votes in the answers indicates that there isn't a generally accepted term.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in the US, 12 oz is the size for 86.347% of all beer sales (totally made up),  but here are 20 ozers and 32 ozers and others, but a serving, per DUI guidelines, is technically 8 oz, so the notion of *serving* is pretty much a fantasy. [Nevertheless, I voted for *serving*.]

Comment: [This definition for beer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/beer) says  **an individual serving of beer; a glass, can, or bottle of beer:**

Comment: 'Defining a term **within the context of a technical paper when one is not readily available** is exactly what is called for' indicates that this is outside the remit of ELU which addresses standard English usage, not 'suggest a word I could press into use here', as has been stated fairly frequently on Meta.

Comment: Personally, if I heard/read "serving of beer" (or other alcoholic beverage), I would assume you meant an amount containing enough pure alcohol that you'd spend about an hour metabolizing it away. Or some similar amount related to the alcohol content and not the packaging.

Answer (score 20):

I would use **can**, and the first time you do this, explain that everything you say equally applies to bottles and you're using the term can for simplicity.

Comment: Unless, of course, the beer comes in bottles?

Comment: @jpaugh "explain that everything you say equally applies to bottles and you're using the term can for simplicity"

Comment: That's an unusual usage of the word "simplicity"...

Comment: @user568458 no, that is normal: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+simplicitly&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Since this question is about academic writing, and I am an academic reader, I would like to make a personal request to the OP: please, please don't do stuff like this. In my field, at least, people rarely read papers straight through, from beginning to end. It's more typical to jump around, skipping backward and forward, reading some parts closely and skimming others. As a result, the first place a reader sees a word is often not the first place it's used. And when a word looks non-technical, readers often assume it means what they think it means...

Answer (score 17):

You could use **drink**.

> Each unit contains twelve bottles of beer, at a price of 70c per drink.

Comment: "Beverage" can also be used if formality is wanted.

Comment: A beer is not a consistent measure. It would be more usual to quote the  price per pint or litre.

Answer (score 8):

I like @uosɐſ's and @Furhmanator's suggestions of just using ***beer***. It's both a mass noun *and* a count noun, so there's no problem saying "price per beer."

- There are six beers in a six pack.
- The average price per beer is $1.25.

Or you might just go with ***subunit*** since they are smaller units within the larger unit (a pack).

- There are six subunits in a six pack.
- The average price per subunit is $1.25.

Answer (score 7):

In the US,  a six-pack or twelve-pack has six or twelve cans or bottles.
I'm afraid you might be stuck with saying 1 can/bottle and explaining it. Or you can just state that you plan to use the word container or unit.

Answer (score 5):

you could try:

## Vessel

> a hollow container for holding liquids
>
> - a container (as a cask, bottle, kettle, cup, or bowl) for holding something

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vessel

Answer (score 5):

For clarity, you might refer to it as a [singleton](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/singleton);

> a person or thing occurring singly, especially an individual set apart
>   from others.

So the sentence would be...

> "***She took the 6-pack and split it into singletons***"

Answer (score 1):

**`Piece`**

While I do not know the beer industry (except as a consumer), in other inventory contexts I have seen the word `piece` used as a subunit.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piece) says:

> A part of a larger whole, usually in such a form that it is able to be separated from other parts.

**`subunit`**

The word [`subunit`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subunit) might work as well.

Answer (score -1):

Following practices in the beverage industry you could call this a Stock Keeping Unit (SKU). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit